# Grails/Groovy - using multiple @TestMixin

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mixins

In Grails I have a service that I want to unit test. The service uses these imports:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.web.JSONBuilder
```

I want the service to do get data and convert it to JSON:

```
def tables = DataProfileStats.withCriteria {
        projections {
            distinct("tableName")               
            }
        };
```

The helper method I wrote to build the JSON is:

```
public String buildNodeString(String nodeText)
{
    def builder = new JSONBuilder();

    JSON result = builder.build {
        hello = "world"
        };

    return result.toString();
}
```

In the unit test I have to add @TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin) so the JSON adapter is loaded. But I also have to add @TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin) so I can mock the database object.

Any ideas on how to have multiple @TestMixin or is this a design issue with me having a import grails.web.JSONBuilder in a service class? Otherwise, I have to use a JAVA/JSON library or put the JSON stuff in a controller.

This is what I want the test to look like:

```
@TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class JsTreeJSONGeneratorServiceTests {

void testSomething() {

    DataProfileStats stats1 = new DataProfileStats();
    stats1.tableName = "table";

    mockDomain(DataProfileStats, stats1);

    JsTreeJSONGeneratorService service = new JsTreeJSONGeneratorService();
    String json = service.buildNodeString();
    assert json != "";

}
```

}

I get a @TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class JsTreeJSONGeneratorServiceTests {

```
void testSomething() {

    DataProfileStats stats1 = new DataProfileStats();
    stats1.tableName = "table";

    mockDomain(DataProfileStats, stats1);

    JsTreeJSONGeneratorService service = new JsTreeJSONGeneratorService();
    String json = service.buildNodeString();
    assert json != "";

}
```

}

I get a @TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class JsTreeJSONGeneratorServiceTests {

```
void testSomething() {

    DataProfileStats stats1 = new DataProfileStats();
    stats1.tableName = "table";

    mockDomain(DataProfileStats, stats1);

    JsTreeJSONGeneratorService service = new JsTreeJSONGeneratorService();
    String json = service.buildNodeString();
    assert json != "";

}
```

}

I get a "Cannot specify duplicate annotation on the same member : grails.test.mixin.TestMixin" exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Found it!

```
@TestMixin([GrailsUnitTestMixin, ControllerUnitTestMixin, DomainClassUnitTestMixin])
```

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from you success.  Cheers~

Comment: Thank you -- this helped me (I was using @Mock() though).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is due to a [Grails bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6222).  The problem with mixing in the `ControllerUnitTextMixin`, is that it also does (and/or potentially will do) a lot of logic unrelated or unhelpful to services, and is essentially a workaround rather than a fix.  Scott's answer is definitely sparse and clean in the sense that no other changes are made, but given some of the lack of backwards compatibility with Grails 2.0, I would be concerned with future releases that may, say, force logic into the setUp() method that may break for services.

So for completeness, I am including another potential workaround taken directly from the [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6222?focusedCommentId=46467&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-46467), all credit to Ellery Crane:

```
package util.converters

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.configuration.ConvertersConfigurationHolder
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.configuration.ConverterConfiguration
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.configuration.DefaultConverterConfiguration
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.ObjectMarshaller
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.Converter
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.configuration.ChainedConverterConfiguration

class JSON extends grails.converters.JSON{

  public JSON(Object target) {
    super(target)
  }

  @Override
  protected ConverterConfiguration<grails.converters.JSON> initConfig() {    
    ConverterConfiguration config = super.initConfig()
    if(config.getOrderedObjectMarshallers().size() == 0){      
      initDefaultMarshallers()
      config = super.initConfig()
    }
    return config
  }

  private void initDefaultMarshallers(){
    List<ObjectMarshaller<grails.converters.JSON>> marshallers = new ArrayList<ObjectMarshaller<grails.converters.JSON>>();
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.ArrayMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.ByteArrayMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.EnumMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.ProxyUnwrappingMarshaller<grails.converters.JSON>());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.DateMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.ToStringBeanMarshaller());

    boolean includeDomainVersion = true;
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.DomainClassMarshaller(includeDomainVersion));
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller());
    marshallers.add(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller());

    DefaultConverterConfiguration<grails.converters.JSON> cfg = new DefaultConverterConfiguration<grails.converters.JSON>(marshallers);
    cfg.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    cfg.setCircularReferenceBehaviour(Converter.CircularReferenceBehaviour.DEFAULT)
    cfg.setPrettyPrint(false);
    ConvertersConfigurationHolder.setDefaultConfiguration(grails.converters.JSON.class, new ChainedConverterConfiguration<grails.converters.JSON>(cfg));
  }
}
```

then

> Just import util.converters.JSON instead of grails.converters.JSON, and everything else works seamlessly.